# Javascript changing the color of text on a button based on user inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I am supposed to create a HTML document with JavaScript that has 3 input (color level) boxes: Red, Green and Blue. It also is supposed to have a input button. The user will insert hex for each color level box 00 through FF.  Once the user has enter the 3 sets of numbers, they click on the input button and it is supposed to change the color of the text on the button to the hex coded color they created.

No matter what I try I can get the input boxes on the HTML page, and enter the 2 digits into all three boxes, but the color of the text on the button does nothing. Other than I click the button, nothing happens.

```js
function AddColors() {
  document.getElementById("tColor").style.color = "#,tColor";
  document.getElementById('tFirstNumber').value +
    document.getElementById('tSecondNumber').value +
    document.getElementById('tThirdNumber').value;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter two-digit, hexadecimal numbers for the amounts of red, green, and blue light you want </ br> combined to create a color.</p>
<p {style text-align: center;}>Enter the hexadecimal numbers in the boxes below.</p>
<p> Amount of <span style="color:#ff0000;">RED</span>: <input id="tFirstNumber" type="text"></p>
<p> Amount of <span style="color:#00ff00;">GREEN</span>: <input id="tSecondNumber" type="text"></p>
<p> Amount of <span style="color:#0000ff;">BLUE</span>: <input id="tThirdNumber" type="text"></p>
<input type="button" value="Click here to see the color you created" id="tColor" onclick="AddColors()" />
```

Comment: Can you please add your code? Without code it is hard for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I thought about that right after I clicked the ask button.  I am getting frustrated and kind of disappointed.  It seems our instructor gets up there and says, we are going to learn a new skill today. Oh and for home work, design a web page off of this fortune cookie size instruction sheet that creates world peace... and it's due tomorrow.

Comment: you've got a duplicate id tag, `tColor`. `id` tags are unique name for only one element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your code has two `id`s, an `id` has to be unique on the whole page
- Your didn't set a variable to hold your input's values
- You got confused about using strings and variables together
- You tried to apply the CSS on the element before you got the values to do so, so your script tried to apply a modifaction it didn't even know about yet

```js
function AddColors() {
  var color =  document.getElementById('tFirstNumber').value +
  document.getElementById('tSecondNumber').value +
  document.getElementById('tThirdNumber').value;
  document.getElementById("tColor").style.color = "#" + color;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter two-digit, hexadecimal numbers for the amounts of red, green, and blue light you want </ br> combined to create a color.</p>
<p {style text-align: center;}>Enter the hexadecimal numbers in the boxes below.</p>
<p> Amount of <span style="color:#ff0000;">RED</span>: <input id="tFirstNumber" type="text"></p>
<p> Amount of <span style="color:#00ff00;">GREEN</span>: <input id="tSecondNumber" type="text"></p>
<p> Amount of <span style="color:#0000ff;">BLUE</span>: <input id="tThirdNumber" type="text"></p>
<p id="tColor">I'll change my color!</p>
<p id="tFirstNumber"></p>
<input type="button" value="Click here to see the color you created" onclick="AddColors()" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed it to do. Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: @RandyAzecloun You're welcome! Please consider marking my answer as the most helping one, so future users with the same problem have it easier to find a solution for their problem!

Answer (score 2):

Your issues were:

- You didn't set a `tColor` variable
- You didn't concatenate the values to the `#` properly in `"#,tColor"`
- You need to set the value on the element after you get the values from your inputs, and you were doing it the other way around
- You duplicated an ID in your HTML and IDs must be unique

```js
function AddColors() {
  tColor = document.getElementById('tFirstNumber').value +
    document.getElementById('tSecondNumber').value +
    document.getElementById('tThirdNumber').value;
    console.log(tColor)
  document.getElementById("tColor").style.color = "#" +tColor;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter two-digit, hexadecimal numbers for the amounts of red, green, and blue light you want </ br> combined to create a color.</p>
<p {style text-align: center;}>Enter the hexadecimal numbers in the boxes below.</p>
<p> Amount of <span style="color:#ff0000;">RED</span>: <input id="tFirstNumber" type="text"></p>
<p> Amount of <span style="color:#00ff00;">GREEN</span>: <input id="tSecondNumber" type="text"></p>
<p> Amount of <span style="color:#0000ff;">BLUE</span>: <input id="tThirdNumber" type="text"></p>
<p id="tColor">your color</p>
<input type="button" value="Click here to see the color you created" id="tColor" onclick="AddColors()" />
```

Comment: The second to last line <p id="tColor">your color</p> was my attempt at getting something to show up anywhere so I could see what it was doing. The whole abomination I had created was supposed to change the color of the text on the button that says "Click here to see the color you created". I was able to get the hello world pop up boxes to work in my previous home work and I mostly got the click to change text to work. Even when I had something a skew in the hello world and changing text something would happen on the screen. Thank you very much for your help.